Converting muliple json records to avro scheme using Python
I'm struggling to find a way of automatic creation of avro schema registry. I have multiple json messages from Mongo DB that I want to use as a basis for creating avro scheme.
Short example of one of the json messages that I have:
{
  "_id": "66eb0139f16c486824ac839e",
  "parent_id": "66eb0139f16c486824ac839b",
  "creation_date": "2024-09-18T16:35:05.667Z",
  "parcel_number": "MP6422003-001",
  "merchant_id": "3517",
  "initial_parcel_price": 5976,
  "weight": 11.66,
  "length": 2200,
  "height": 110,
  "width": 160,
  "route": {
    "route_parts": [
      {
        "creation_date": "2024-09-18T16:35:05.667Z",
        "start_point_terminal": {
          "address": {
            "geo_id": "743095",
            "region": "", 
          "terminal_type": 2,
          "owner": "3517",
          "storage_period": null,
          "terminal_code": ""
        }
       ]
    }
}

From this I want to obtain AVRO scheme with data types.
I've already tried to use several packages that supposedly convert json to avro, but eventually it turned out that avro.schema package doesn't parse json messages. The following code gives an error 'SchemaParseException: No "type" property'.
with open('test_json.json', 'r') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
schema = avro.schema.parse(json.dumps(json_data))

Maybe there is a way to convert json message to json schema and then convert json schema to avro?

This is what I found with:
"How to convert JSON to Avro in python"
And then the first link from the result:
https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=254e8ae6c877f940&sca_upv=1&q=How%20to%20convert%20JSON%20to%20Avro%20in%20python&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiP8ZeoqNiIAxUg0AIHHSHHNacQ1QJ6BAg3EAE&biw=412&bih=833&dpr=2.63#sbfbu=1&pi=How%20to%20convert%20JSON%20to%20Avro%20in%20python

This link is about converting files themselves from json to avro. My question is about converding json document to avro scheme.

So you want to convert data to a schema?
This is one of the steps: create a schema for the Avro data. Without it, Avro data cannot be written.
Or you serahc for it: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+create+an+AVRO+schema+for+my+JSON+data%3F&oq=How+to+create+an+AVRO+schema+for+my+JSON+data%3F&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIGCAEQRRg8MgYIAhAuGEDSAQc0NzRqMGoxqAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
